# Graph type showing aggregate id⇒(before, after)?

Tags: info-visualisation, charts, visual-design

What's the category of graphs for showing this?

```
ID | before | after
-------------------
0  | 45.6   | 24.3
-------------------
1  | 1.7    | 89.5
-------------------
⋮  | ⋮      | ⋮
```

I was thinking something like:

```
    _______________________________________________________________________________
100|
   |     /^
   |     |
75 |     /
   |     |
   |     |
50 |     |
   |  ^\ |
   |    \/
25 |   / \
   |  |   ^
   |  |
0  |  ^
```

With colours and different thicknesses it could be a good visual representation…

Comment: Hmm, could this be it? [Parallel coordinates](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#parallel-coordinates)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be referring to **[slopegraphs](http://charliepark.org/slopegraphs/)**

From **[Seeing Data](http://seeingdata.org/taketime/inside-the-chart-slope-graph/)**

> A slope graph can be used to show a ‘before and after’ story of different values, based on comparing their values at different points in time. The related values are connected by slopes. It might be used to show change in food and drink prices between two years, as in this example on the right.

[image]

Comment: That's the one! - Don't recall seeing it before; thanks